# Pyorient query To Json

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientdb

i'm using OrientDB with python 3.5 and i create a API for my records. Problem is i got the records but i need to serialize these records.

here its my code.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
import pyorient

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424)
client.set_session_token( True )  # set true to enable the token based

client.db_open( "intera", "admin", "admin" )

### store this token somewhere
sessionToken = client.get_session_token()

### destroy the old client, equals to another user/socket/ip ecc.
del client

### create a new client
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424)

### set the previous obtained token to re-attach to the old session
client.set_session_token( sessionToken )

### now the dbOpen is not needed to perform database operations

### set the flag again to true if you want to renew the token
client.set_session_token( True )  # set true
client.db_open( "intera", "admin", "admin" )
new_sessionToken = client.get_session_token()

assert sessionToken != new_sessionToken


class TodoList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        query = client.command("select * from my_class")



api.add_resource(TodoList,'/todos')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug =True)
```

[thats the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZwPz.png)

how can i fix that error and serialize these records.